# remove circular symbolic links

Tags: bash, symlink

I want to remove circular symbolic links.
The issue here is how do I correctly parse out the circular link generated by the find -follow command?

```
 find /home/ -follow -printf ""
find: File system loop detected; `/home/domain_names_new/biz/2015-04-09_03_44_31/2015-04-09_03_44_31' is part of the same file system loop as `/home/domain_names_new/biz/2015-04-09_03_44_31'.
find: File system loop detected; `/home/domain_names_new/biz/2015-04-09_03_44_31/2015-04-13_03_44_03/2015-04-09_03_44_31' is part of the same file system loop as `/home/domain_names_new/biz/2015-04-09_03_44_31'.
find: File system loop detected; `/home/domain_names_new/biz/2015-04-09_03_44_31/2015-04-13_03_44_03/2015-04-13_03_44_03' is part of the same file system loop as `/home/domain_names_new/biz/2015-04-09_03_44_31/2015-04-13_03_44_03'.
```

Comment: just look where every file is pointing to: use `ls -l`

Answer (score 3):

This is what I'd use to remove the children links using the output of the find follow:

```
find /home/ -type l -follow -printf "" 2>&1 | grep -i 'system loop' | sed -e "s/.*detected; \`\(.*\)' is part.*/\1/" | xargs rm
```

first redirect error stream to stdout:

```
2>&1
```

then prefilter for those messages that warn about a symlink loop (find calls this a *file system loop*), in case there are other debug messages from find, e.g. permission denied. In case no line is selected we still exit with return code `0` by checking if the return code of grep was `1`.

```
grep -i 'system loop'
```

extract the filename between "detected; " and "' is part"

```
sed -e "s/.*detected; \`\(.*\)' is part.*/\1/" :
```

delete the corresponding file

```
xargs rm
```

Comment: Thanks Pierrick this works like a charm! I took the liberty to make an edit in case there are non symlink loop related messages from find. E.g. permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like /home/domain_names_new/biz/2015-04-09_03_44_31/2015-04-09_03_44_31 is pointing to its parent folder /home/domain_names_new/biz/2015-04-09_03_44_31 . You can check this using

```
ls -l /home/domain_names_new/biz/2015-04-09_03_44_31/2015-04-09_03_44_31
```

NOTE: the two other errors have a similar problem; each time a link pointing to its parent folder.

so you need to remove this link or correct it. There is no "magic" solution; only YOU know where the links should point to, the system cannot know this.

Comment: @user121196 : if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it.